# How to craete the Ms Project from Excel on VB

Tags: excel

How create MS Project file from Excel with settings (with calendar and file name)?

I can't give a name to the future file and specify a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

First, open MS Project and make a new project with nothing in it.

Then, click on the "Project" tab and select "Project Information."

In the box that pops up, choose the calendar you want by clicking on the drop-down menu.

After that, close the box. Next, go to Excel and save your file with the name you want.

Now, go back to MS Project and click on the "File" tab, then select "Open."

Find your Excel file where you saved it and select it.

In the box that appears, choose "Microsoft Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)" as the file type, then click "Open."

In the "Import Wizard," select the part of the Excel file you want to import into MS Project.

Then, follow the instructions to set up the import settings, like matching up the columns in Excel with the fields in Project.

Finally, click "Finish" to finish the import.